# Using for*/first correctly with annotations in Typed Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, typed-racket

I'm trying to understand how to use a `for*/first` loop in Typed Racket. Because everytime I try to execute my code I get a exception, that I need to add more annotations.

I have the following `for*/first` loop:

```
(for*/first ([current-pos : Integer (in-range start-pos -1 -1)]
             #:when (char=? (string-ref input-string current-pos) character))
  current-pos)
```

If I understand the [official typed racket reference](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html?q=for#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._for%2A%2Ffirst%29%29) right, the type-annotations in a `for*/first`-loop are completely optional, but the values used in the loop must all be from the same type.

I checked now the seq-expr `in-range` for it's type and it's an Sequence of Integers `(Sequenceof Integer)` and the `current-pos` is annotated as an `Integer`, so every value is de-facto an Integer. In the reference there is also mentioned the `#:when` must be the last for-clause (exactly like in my piece of code).

Nevertheless every time I execute the code I get the error message:

> Type Checker: Error in macro expansion -- insufficient type information to typecheck. please add more type annotations in: (for*/first ((current-pos : Integer (in-range start-pos -1 -1)) #:when (char=? (string-ref input-string current-pos) character)) current-pos)

So my question: **How to write a for*/first loop in typed racket with correct annotations?**

There is also a similar looking question on stackoverflow, but the solution was only up-to-date before they added the possiblity to use the overloaded `for*/first` instead of the `for*/first:` function. But it was for me not possible to comment these question because of the "you-need-a-reputation-of-50-to-comment-policy".

---

I have experimented a little bit in the REPL, the problem must be lying in the return value of the `for*/first`-loop. I have now converted the `for*/first`-loop to a `for/list` loop and applied `car` on the result, it's a little bit tricky but at least it works.

Comment: `for/first` and `for*/first` do not work in typed racket no matter what type annotations you put on them. However, you can try using `for/or` instead. It's very similar in that it returns the first non-false value.

Comment: The `for/first` form is documented as not being supported, but the `for*/first` form isn't currently. I've made a pull request to fix that.

Comment: @AlexKnauth I actually tried and make it work with `for/list` so I guessed the answer would be that it was a bug. Wouldn't `for/first` be somewhat similar to `for/or` in terms of implementation?

Comment: `(first (for/list ...))` is not what you want; it iterates through everything instead of stopping after the first successful iteration. `for/first` and `for/or` are very similar in behavior and how they iterate, but `for/first` expands to a multiple-accumulator `for/fold` loop with a `let-values` around it, while `for/or` uses only a one-accumulator `for/fold` loop and doesn't need a `let-values`.